# Autoscroll not working on SplitContainer in WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms, which contains a SplitContainer control. The SplitContainer has a DataGridView in SplitContainer.Panel1 and a UserControl in SplitContainer.Panel2. In SplitContainer.Panel1 the DataGridView has autoscrolling working fine (I did not do anything here, it's automatic I guess), but on SplitContainer.Panel2 it doesn't.

The UserControl loaded in SplitContainer.Panel2 has two Panels inside, just in case someone would ask :) Autoscroll seems to work when a very little portion of the SplitContainer.Panel2 is visible, but not on the whole UserControl.

This is the relevant code in constructor of Form:

```
InitializeComponent();
var infoPanel = InfoPanelUserControl.Instance;
infoPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
infoPanel.AutoScroll = true;
dataSplitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(infoPanel);
dataSplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```

This is the method executed when clicking a cell in DataGridView:

```
dataSplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = false;
var row = Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridView) sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Id"].Value);
var record = Repository.Instance.Passmann.Vaults.First().Records.Single(x => x.Id == row);
InfoPanelUserControl.Instance.LoadInfo(record);
```

I've tried adding AutoScroll property on different controls (to SplitContainer.Panel2, UserControl) and also AutoSize, but none of these seems to work.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try setting Panel2's autoscroll to true, and InfoPanelUserControl's Dock to Top instead of Fill.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot.

PS: Can you explain why I was wrong? I still don't get it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that if you set it to fill, then it will always be the size of the container (panel2), while it needs to be bigger for a scrollbar to show. Setting it to Top ensures it's the correct width and that there's no space at the top but lets it grow vertically, so it can be bigger than the panel.